# Can't loop through my interface element with *ngFor in html file of Angular 2

Tags: angular, html, interface, model-binding, angular2-directives

I am getting data from API through my Interface but unable to show those data with the help of `*ngFor` directives in Html File.

Below is my Interface named LabRateInterface

```
export interface second1 {
  user: number;
}

export interface third1 {
  user: number;
}

export interface Healthpackages {
  second: second1;
  third: third1;
}

export interface PrePaid {
  block_on_zero_balance: boolean;
  deposit: any[];
  max_recharge: number;
}

export interface HealthPackage {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  mrp: number;
  user: number;
  available: boolean;
  cashback: number;
}

export interface Testgroup {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  user: number;
  mrp: number;
  cashback: number;
  available: boolean;
}

export interface Time {
  to: string;
  from: string;
}

export interface Days {
  sat: boolean;
  fri: boolean;
  thu: boolean;
  wed: boolean;
  tue: boolean;
  mon: boolean;
  sun: boolean;
}

export interface Timing {
  time: Time;
  days: Days;
}

export interface Facilities {
  online_report: boolean;
  nabl: boolean;
  parking: boolean;
  ac: boolean;
  insurance: boolean;
  credit_card: boolean;
  home_collection: boolean;
}

export interface Admin {
  password: string;
  username: string;
}

export interface Geolocation {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
}

export interface ReportHeader {
  line4: string;
  line3: string;
  line2: string;
  line1: string;
}

export interface Cover {
  mobile: string;
  image: string;
}

export interface LabsRatelistInterface {
  _id: string;
  __v: number;
  address: string;
  created_on: Date;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  phone: string;
  rating: number;
  healthpackages: Healthpackages;
  home_collection_price: number;
  pre_paid: PrePaid;
  reviews: any[];
  health_packages: HealthPackage[];
  testgroups: Testgroup[];
  timing: Timing;
  home_collection: boolean;
  lab_visit: boolean;
  home_collection_only: boolean;
  facilities: Facilities;
  employees: any[];
  admin: Admin;
  contacts: any[];
  city: string;
  geolocation: Geolocation;
  report_header: ReportHeader;
  cover: Cover;
  camp: boolean;
  franchisee: boolean;
  publish: boolean;
}
```

Now I make a variable `labsRateInterface:LabsRatelistInterface;`

```
onChange(event) {
  console.log(event.value);
  this.labsRatelistService.getlabs(event.value).subscribe(
    ShowData => {
      this.labsRateInterface = ShowData;
      console.log(this.labsRateInterface);
      for (let i = 0; i < this.labsRateInterface.testgroups.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.labsRateInterface.testgroups[i].name)
      }
    }, error => {
      this.statusMessage = error;
    });
}
```

and finally below is my HTML where I want to print the list of test group

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let test of labsRateInterface.testgroups; let i=index">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{test._id}}</td>
    <td>{{test.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

But It is showing an error "testgroup property of undefined" and not printing anything.

Comment: use *ngFor = `let test of labsRateInterface.testgroups` instead of `let test of testgroups`

Comment: Already tried that solution, still not working

Comment: can you show me the data coming from api? I need to see the data present in `ShowData` or `this.labsRateInterface`

Comment: what happens if you try this? `let test of labsRateInterface?.testgroups`

Comment: Are you getting the console value using this:  `console.log(this.labsRateInterface.testgroups[i].name)`

Comment: here is the google drive link of the data https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AdvBnzf1S-bgt9dappoXoVBuQNycMdGPXLUNOw5icoM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes i am getting the console value

Comment: Fork this **[Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9wvwo9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)** make changes on it according to what you did at your end and help me replicate your issue then. Please share your implementation then. I'll have a look at it

Comment: got my answer, it started working by using ? operator @SiddAjmera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use safe navigation operator `?`,

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let test of labsRateInterface?.testgroups; let i=index">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{test._id}}</td>
    <td>{{test.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: But i want to know the reason behind this solution , how it is working behind the scene??

Comment: @MRIGANKTAXAK Initially when you declare a variable, its value will be undefined. So when you try to use it, it will throw such errors. Safe navigation prevents such exceptions by using the variable only when its not null or undefined.

Comment: How " ? " operator helps?

Comment: @MRIGANKTAXAK That is called the safe navigation operator. Refer [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-safe-navigation-operator-in-angular-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Async pipe.

Since the result in totally based on the observable which is asynchronous. So its better to use async pipe.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let test of labsRateInterface.testgroups | async; let i=index">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{test._id}}</td>
    <td>{{test.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```